# Data extention REST API fails during inserting

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data

Lets say we've got followed code

```javascript
var createDE = createDE(dataExtensionName,fieldNamesArray);
// TODO check for correct response value
if(createDE.Status == "OK") 
{
   var deObjectID = createDE.Results[0].NewObjectID;  
} 
else { var res = createDE; } 
             
var deKey = 'csv_' + dataExtensionName + '_' + deObjectID;
var endPoint = restEndpoint + "data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:" + deKey + "/rows";
var request = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(endPoint);
request.continueOnError = true;
request.emptyContentHandling = 0;
request.retries = 2;
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Variable.GetValue("@accessToken"));
request.method = "POST";
request.contentType = "application/json";
request.encoding = "UTF-8";
request.postData = csvData;
var response = request.send();
var content = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(response.content));
```

i've got requestId but when trying to check the status always get

```json
{
    "page": 0,
    "pageSize": 0,
    "count": 0,
    "items": [],
    "requestId": "566e00f7-d550-4028-9b34-a729e6a63975",
    "resultMessages": [
        {
            "resultType": "Operational",
            "resultClass": "Error",
            "resultCode": "AsyncRequestStatusNotFound",
            "message": "Unable to locate an Async Request Status Record for the provided RequestId: 897c4c35-90f5-42ab-950e-7824b12c9c3d."
        }
    ]
}
```

i'm wondering if there is some solution for this issue?
POSTMAN performs the same successfully and i get new records in data extention

---

Even this snippet doesn't work

```
Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey("getTokenAdminFrontend");
     try {
       var endPoint = restEndpoint + "data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:csvImportBulkLog/rows";
       var request = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(endPoint);
       var logData = {
        requestId :  Platform.Function.GUID(),
        modifiedBy: "test@test.xyz",
        DEKey: "sometestDE"
       };
        request.continueOnError = true;
        request.emptyContentHandling = 0;
        request.retries = 2;
        request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Variable.GetValue("@accessToken"));
        request.method = "PUT";
        request.contentType = "application/json";
        request.encoding = "UTF-8";
        request.postData = String(logData);
        var response = request.send();
        var content = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(response.content));
        var requestId = content.requestId;
 
      } catch(e) {
       
      }
```

Comment: Do you have your "csvData" payload variable as a string?

Comment: Yes, csvData is got prepared on a front end and passed go ssjs

Comment: Ok, I am not sure based on your answer whether `csvData` is a string but just try to have it like this `Stringify(csvData)` within your code.

Comment: in case when i use Stringify(csvData) i dont even get requestId. Once more i send it as a stringified value using kinda $('#csvData').val(JSON.stringify({"items": currentChunk})); and send serialized form via AJAX. Then i read this string as var csvData = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("csvData");